# how to change the output of woocommerce shortcodes?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

when I use woocommerce shortcodes it have a special layout of html as the output!
for example if i use the shortcode: `<?php echo do_shortcode['[products]']?>`
it will show the the products in a certain layout of html like this:

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="product-grid">
   <ul>
    <li>
    <li>
    <li>
    <li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
```

and there is a certain layout of html inside the li.
now my question is how can i change the layout of html that the shortcode is generating?

Comment: You're better to just write your own WP_Query and loop over the results outputting the products in whatever format you like.  This link shows some examples of what is possible. https://www.gavick.com/blog/wp_query-woocommerce-products

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.GO TO `functions.php` of the corresponding `plugin/theme` root folder.

2.search this page by `product-grid` or any common `class` appeared in this layout.

3.You will find a function for this shortcode.